# Ubuntu Server 16.04.3 boots, but no login prompt

Tags: boot, server, login

I have freshly installed Ubuntu Server 16.04.3. I had previously been using some edition of version 14, and it always booted to a text login screen. I was expecting the same from 16.04.3, and in on-line demos that's exactly what I see happening.

It essentially gets to a black screen with no login prompt and only the following text at top:

```
/dev/md0: clean, 60884/117891072 files, 759991/471562752 blocks
```

I do have (software) RAID10 configured. This is my first time configuring anything other than RAID0.

I noticed that I am able to ssh into the machine remotely and use it that way. I also discovered that by typing Ctrl-Alt-1 I can get to a (colourful) terminal and login that way. I've seen some other people ask about boot/log-in issues, but most seem to involve boot loops or completely blank screens. This doesn't seem to be what I'm experiencing.

So my problem doesn't seem to indicate the server isn't booted correctly. It just doesn't present the login screen to the local terminal automatically after booting. Is this expected?

Additional information:

Relevant contents of /var/log/auth.log

```
systemd-logind[825]: New seat seat0.
systemd-logind[825]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event1 (Power Button)
systemd-logind[825]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event0 (Power Button)
sshd[968]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
sshd[968]: Server listening on :: port 22.
CRON[1290]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
CRON[1290]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```

Comment: You installed a server it doesn't come with a GUI, if you need it you have install that!

Comment: I'm not expecting a GUI, nor do I want one. I'm expecting a CLI login prompt, much like you'd get with SSH. Basically I was anticipating the same default behaviour as with Ubuntu 14.04 server.

Comment: Inspect `/var/log/auth.log` if there's an auth issue.

Comment: I didn't see an issue there, or at least none that I recognize. Seems like it was just waiting for events.

`>>systemd-logind[825]: New seat seat0.
>>systemd-logind[825]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event1 (Power Button)
>>systemd-logind[825]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event0 (Power Button)
>>sshd[968]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
>>sshd[968]: Server listening on :: port 22.
>>CRON[1290]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
>>CRON[1290]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root`

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post, when you want to add information? Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) will be much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Comment: There was a separate question linked from David Foerster's link that solved the problem. Removing "quiet splash" from GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT in /etc/default/grub worked. I've added the question "How do I set 'nomodeset' after I've already installed Ubuntu?" to the list of duplicates.

Comment: Make sure TTY isn't screwing you.  Press CTRL + ALT + F1 and you might see the login prompt.  Read more here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/761031/ubuntu-server-16-04-installs-on-sdc-but-fails-to-boot